# fibonnaci Series code in python

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote this code in python 2.7 to find Fibonnaci series. But there is error in my code:

```
File "Fib.py", line 2, in <module>
    class Fib:
  File "Fib.py", line 21, in Fib
    for n in Fib(4):
NameError: name 'Fib' is not defined
```

Can anyone resolve this bug?

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self,max):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.a=0
        self.b = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self) :
        fib = self.a
        if fib > self.max :
            raise StopIteration 
        a,b=b,self.a+self.b
        return fib

for n in Fib(4):
    print n
```

Comment: Hello, I've edited your question so it has nice code formatting. But I'm worried that I may have changed the indentation from what you originally had. Does this look right? In particular, does your `for n in Fib(4):` line have no indentation at all?

Comment: That's quite different from the error I get from that code.

Comment: `a,b=b,self.a+self.b` should probably be `self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a+self.b`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I cannot reproduce your error *from the code you posted (see below for my guess work)*. However, I still get errors, so I'll fix them.

## From your posted code:

---

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 17, in <module>
    for n in Fib(4):
TypeError: instance has no next() method
```

It seems, if your targeting python 2.7, that you got mixed up with python 3. The `__next__` method was introduced in python 3 (in [PEP 3114](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/), if your interested). In python 2, use `next`. Also, as `self` must be used to access instance member variables, `a,b=b,self.a+self.b` should be `self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b`. This makes your code:

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
        return self

    def next(self):
        fib = self.a
        if fib > self.max :
            raise StopIteration 
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        return fib

for n in Fib(4):
    print n
```

Which produces the output:

```
0
1
1
2
3
```

Note that changing the `next` to `__next__` and changing `print n` to `print(n)` makes this work in python 3 (but then not python 2. If you want both you need to forward `next` to `__next__` and use brackets for `print`).

## Guessed actual code:

---

Judging from your error, your original code probably looked like:

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self,max):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.a=0
        self.b = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self) :
        fib = self.a
        if fib > self.max :
            raise StopIteration 
        a,b=b,self.a+self.b
        return fib

    for n in Fib(4):  # Note that this makes the loop part of the class body
        print n
```

Indenting the `for` loop makes it part of the class body, and as the class name is a name not yet accessible, it raises a `NameError`. For a simpler example, try (it gives a similar error):

```
class A:
    print A
```

Therefore, the error you experience is most likely just an indentation mixup. Nice idea using an iterator, though.

Answer (score 0):

Easier method to implemented fibonacci series:

```
known = {0:0, 1:1}


def fibonacci(n) : 

    if n in known:
        return known[n]
    res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    known[n] = res
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fibonnaci Series with recursion

```
def fib(term_num):  
    if term_num == 0 or term_num ==1:
        return term_num
    return fib(term_num-2) + fib(term_num-1)
    
for x in range(1,11):  
    print(fib(x))
```

Output Below:
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55